# pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS operation timed

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I am trying to connect the Mongo database with fast API, some i am able to make successful connection, on any code change happen, and restart the server i am getting below error

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS operation timed out after 21.168028831481934 seconds
```

I am using the below versions

```
python: 3.8.2
fastapi==0.62.0
motor==2.3.0
databases==0.5.5
odmantic==0.4.0
pydantic==1.8.2
```

below is code for making connection

```python
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from ..core.config import MONGODB_URL, MAX_CONNECTIONS_COUNT, MIN_CONNECTIONS_COUNT
import asyncio
from odmantic import AIOEngine


class DataBase:
    client: AsyncIOMotorClient = None

db = DataBase()
db.client = AsyncIOMotorClient(str(MONGODB_URL))
db.client.get_io_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop
engine = AIOEngine(motor_client=db.client)
```

Comment: You forgot to paste your error